# FireMonkey access SQL Server on Android or iOS

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Is there any way to access a SQL Server database using Delphi XE5 FireMonkey in an Android or iOS application? There doesn't appear to be a way to do it using FireDAC or UniDAC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to access SQL Server from iOS and Android is via DataSnap. You have to make a DataSnap-Server on a Windows-Machine that connects to SQL Server. The iOS and Android clients then connect to the DataSnap-Server.

Comment: Why is it different from desktop? In vcl we connect to SQL directly via FireDac. In mobile you told we need to connect to a server via Datasnap and then the server connects to SQL. Why is that so?

Comment: FireDAC relies on a driver to connect to SQL Server and I am not aware of any SQL Server drivers being available for Android or iOS.
BTW, the answer is a bit outdated as currently the recommended way is using REST.

Comment: Using REST to call the api that is a datasnap server made in vcl?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are no clients available in Delphi that would allow you to access a SQL Server from Android and iOS.

FireDAC is the standard way to access, but mobile is only available to access Interbase (ToGo version) and SQLite.

The logical thing would be to use **DataSnap** or **Webservice** on the server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a DataSnap Rest Server (http,https)
2. Create methods that return JSON
3. Consume that methods from client(Android/IOS)

DP